# I want to open Pdf in browser in asp.net but don't want user can copy / download the pdf.How we can do that

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to open Pdf in browser in asp.net but don't want user can copy / download the pdf or How we can disable right click in pdf viewer in browser

Answer (score 0):

It is a browser feature which means you have no control over it. You can use third party tools.

http://googlesystem.blogspot.com.br/2009/09/embeddable-google-document-viewer.html

Comment: But that PDF is not stored in folder or not on google drive.I am creating PDF from c# and open it in browser when user clicked on link.